# Use AJAX to return database info

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a script that I intend to automate that copies a database table.  I've been informed about replication but I have no idea of how to get it working properly, so I've decided to use this method instead.

To try and minimize security risks, our live site is going to make requests for the database table that our other site regularly uses.  The request script, which I'll refer to as request.php, is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Idea is to use this to get response to provide table data
            //What goes here?
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
        //Define database handler
        $dbWriter = new mysqli(database connection info);

        if($mysqli->connect_errno){
            $errorMessage = sprintf("'%s'", $mysqli->connect_error);
            echo $errorMessage;
        }
        else{
            $dbWriter->query("DELETE * FROM qb_inventory_status");

            //Processing of data goes here
            foreach($returnedItems as $item){
                //Create query to insert individual records
                $start = "INSERT INTO table(fieldA, fieldB...) VALUES (";
                $end = sprintf("'%s', %d, %d, %f, %f)", fieldA, fieldB...);
                $start .= $end;

                //Database handler uses $start to insert record
                $dbWriter->query($start);
            }

            $dbWriter->close();
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

The response script (response.php) is as follows.

```
<?php
require_once($documentRoot."/classes/DBHandler.php");

$db_controller = new DBHandler();

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $db_controller->select($query);

//This array is what should be returned so request.php can handle it
while($rowObject=mysql_fetch_object($rs)){        
    $rtnItems[]=$rowObject;
}

//Return $rtnItems here

?>
```

I know how to retrieve information from a database and put it in a format suitable for processing within the same file, but when it comes to a situation like this, I'm not sure how to pass it back to request.php.  How can I make this work?  I need to be able to write the returned array to the database.  I've never done the latter process with Javascript before, so I was also wondering if it's possible to access the returned database with the PHP portion of request.php.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking for (although it sounds like you want an introductory Ajax tutorial which would be too broad for SO) but if you are trying to fake database replication by using a web browser as a middleman to copy everything over HTTP … stop! That way lies madness.

Comment: If it's not safe as you claim, then provide information on why that is rather than just telling me that there are better ways to go about doing this, and explain what some of those methods are.  I'm not gaining anything from people simply telling me not to do something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the basic of ajax with something like this

To call

```
$.ajax({url: "response.php", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
 }});
```

Check always the references on jquery 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Result in this case is the info you want to "paste" in your frontend.

Use the data handler in response (to retrieve the info), you dont need it in the frontend UNLESS you are querying directly from it.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't need to display anything on that page.  It exists solely to acquire the data from the other site's database table, then use said data to write to its own copy.  I haven't seen anything that indicates the possibility of transferring the returned array into request.php's own PHP script.  The idea is that this thing needs to run by itself.  I can accomplish that with a task scheduler.

Comment: You have request.php, what do you want to do there?

Comment: That file calls to response.php, which is on a different server and I must therefore refer to it with its full URL.  Response.php sends a database table back to request.php.  Request.php uses this returned array to write to its own database table.

Comment: and why do you need ajax? have you read about cURL?